# Minimum steps to win Snake Ladder

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Given a snake and ladder game, write a function that returns the minimum number of jumps to take top or destination position. 
You can assume the die you throws results in always favor of you

**

> Here is my solution, but not sure it's correct or not.
>
> This problem is similar to frog jump in an array.But before that we
>   will have to model the problem in that format.
>
> Create an array of size 100 and for each position store 6 if there is
>   no snake or ladder. store jump count . if ladder is present at that
>   point . If snake is present then store -ve jump at that location.
>
> Now we have to solve in how many minimum steps we can reach till end.
>   Main problem can be solved using dynamic programing in O(n^2) time
>   complexity and O(n ) space.

Comment: Try BFS(Breadth First Search). Runtime will be O(N*6)=O(N) as from a certain point you'll move at most 6 cells forward.

Comment: @Fallen, Yes, but out of those six steps, I have to choose the one with maximum ladder jump and avoid the one with snake position. Right?

Comment: I used simulation to solve this problem at my [blog](http://programmingpraxis.com/2011/03/04/chutes-and-ladders/). My solution is in Scheme; there are also solutions in Haskell and Python. In addition to simulation, commenters used transition matrices and Dijkstra's shortest-path algorithm to find solutions.

Comment: Please put comments and reason if you are down voting this. There is no point in down voting without any comment.

Comment: For a scaleable approach I would definately think Dijkstra shortest path, however given the size of the problem it can easily be brute forced. (6^7 isn't a lot).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at [this](http://www.datagenetics.com/blog/november12011/index.html) blog post, it does a full mathematical analysis of Chutes and Ladders, using both Monte-Carlo simulations and Markov chains. He does show a way of calculating the minimum number of steps to win (basically construct a transition matrix and see how many times you have to multiply the starting vector to get to a solution that has a non-zero final position). This is probably not the most efficient way of doing it, but the post is well worth the read.

Here is a quick solution in python, using sets. I got the numbers in the jump-table from the blog post. At every step, it simply calculates all the positions reachable from the previous step, and continues to do so until the final position is among the reachable positions:

```
jumps = {1: 38, 4: 14, 9: 31, 21: 42, 28: 84, 36: 44, 51: 67, 71: 91, 80: 100,
  98: 78, 95: 75, 93: 73, 87: 24, 64: 60, 62: 19, 56: 53, 49: 11, 48: 26, 16: 6}
final_pos = 100
positions = {0} #initial position off the board
nsteps = 0

while final_pos not in positions:
    nsteps += 1
    old_positions = positions
    positions = set()
    for pos in old_positions:
        for dice in range(1, 7):
            new_pos = pos + dice
            positions.add(jumps.get(new_pos, new_pos))

print 'Reached finish in %i steps' % nsteps
```

Execution time is negligible and it spits out the correct answer (see blog) of 7.

Comment: There are chances that all 6 consecutive position have jumps to previous position and not able to reach the final position.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple breadth-first search solution in Python:

```python
# the target square and the positions of the snakes and ladders:
top = 100
jump = { 1: 38,  4: 14,  9: 31, 16:  6, 21: 42, 28: 84, 36: 44,
        48: 26, 49: 11, 51: 67, 56: 53, 62: 19, 64: 60, 71: 91,
        80:100, 87: 24, 93: 73, 95: 75, 98: 78}

# start from square 0 (= outside the board) after 0 rolls
open = {0}
path = {0: ()}

while len(open) > 0:
    i = open.pop()
    p = path[i] + (i,)
    for j in xrange(i+1, i+7):
        if j > top: break
        if j in jump: j = jump[j]
        if j not in path or len(path[j]) > len(p):
            open.add(j)
            path[j] = p

for i in path:
    print "Square", i, "can be reached in", len(path[i]), "rolls via", path[i]
```

The board layout (i.e. the `jump` dictionary) is taken from the [blog post](http://www.datagenetics.com/blog/november12011/index.html) linked to by Bas Swinckels in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18321734).
This code will print (one of the) shortest path(s) to each reachable square on the board, ending with:

```
Square 100 can be reached in 7 rolls via (0, 38, 41, 45, 67, 68, 74)
```

If you want the full output, see [this demo on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/o82mfl).

Comment: It will be wrong if I don't write `if j in jump: j = jump[j]` before writing `open.add(j)`. Right? I just saw [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/snake-ladder-problem-2/) and apprehensive of the code that's written may be wrong bcz. they are not putting the `jump[j]` into the queue. Kindly check

Comment: If using queue instead set for variable open, then no need to compare the "len(path[j]) > len(p):" since it's now visited in order by depth. Using set has the problem that the nodes may not arrive in order due to jumps, so node with smaller depth may pop first than larger one, which requires comparison of "len(path[j]) > len(p)", and that is not strictly "BFS" anymore

Answer (score 1):

I've implemented this in C#. You can check my gist [here](https://gist.github.com/aboo/64d409f583188c0c1d9d). I will also paste the code below.

In my implementation I've considered the followings:

- **avoiding loops** : This happens when a snake crosses a ladder. For example when end of a ladder is head of a snake and tail of the snake is start of the same ladder. That's a simple example but there might be more complex loops.
- **taking good snakes** : I noticed that you don't need to avoid all the snakes. Sometimes you need to take the snake since it helps you to get to the target quicker. I call them "good snakes". For example 3>60 then **61>50** then 51>100 (target). If you take the snake the min dice count will be 3 and without the snake 8.
- **optional and mandatory jumps** : When optional jump is set to false the algorithm has to take the jump when gets to one.
- **shortest way awareness** : When the algorithm gets to the target it will register the shortest way and during the calculation it will drop searches that are longer that the current found solution. That makes the process a lot faster in complex situations.

  ```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  namespace SnakeAndLaddersSolution
  {
    public class SnakeAndLadder
    {
      private struct Jump
     {
       public int Start;
       public int End;
     }

     private const int TOP = 100;
     private const int STEP_SIZE = 6;
     private int _minDiceCount = int.MaxValue;
     private readonly List<Jump> _jumps = new List<Jump>();

     public bool OptionalJump { get; set; }

     public void AddJump(int start, int end)
     {
         _jumps.Add(new Jump { Start = start, End = end });
     }

     public int Solve()
     {
         var path = new Stack<int>();
         path.Push(1); //start from square 1
         return FindMinimumDice(path, 0);
     }

     private int FindMinimumDice(Stack<int> path, int diceCount)
     {
         if (diceCount >= _minDiceCount)
         {
             //too long. we've already found a shortest path.
             //drop going deeper
             return -1;
         }
         var currentSquare = path.Peek();
         var diceCounts = new List<int>();
         int newDiceCount;

         var ignoreNormalJump = false;

      for (var i = 0; i <= STEP_SIZE; i++)
      {
          var newSquare = currentSquare + i;
          if (newSquare == TOP)
          {
              //got there
              var totalDiceCount = diceCount + (i == 0 ? 0 : 1);
              _minDiceCount = Math.Min(_minDiceCount, totalDiceCount); //register the shortest path
              return totalDiceCount;
          }


          if (_jumps.All(j => j.Start != newSquare)) continue; //only process jumps

          var jump = _jumps.First(j => j.Start == newSquare);
          if (path.Contains(jump.End))
              continue; //already been here
          path.Push(jump.Start);
          path.Push(jump.End);
          newDiceCount = FindMinimumDice(path, diceCount + (i == 0 ? 0 : 1));
          path.Pop();
          path.Pop();
          if (newDiceCount != -1)
              diceCounts.Add(newDiceCount);
          if (i == 0 && !OptionalJump) //the current squre is a jump that should be taken
          {
              ignoreNormalJump = true;
              break;
          }
      }
      if (!ignoreNormalJump)
      {
          var longestJump = 0;
          for (var i = STEP_SIZE; i > 0; i--)
          {
              if (_jumps.All(j => j.Start != currentSquare + i))
              {
                  longestJump = currentSquare + i;
                  break;
              }
          }
          if (longestJump != 0)
          {
              path.Push(longestJump);
              newDiceCount = FindMinimumDice(path, diceCount + 1);
              path.Pop();
              if (newDiceCount != -1)
                  diceCounts.Add(newDiceCount);
          }
      }
      return !diceCounts.Any() ? -1 : diceCounts.Min();
     }
    }

    class Program
    {

     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
         var sal = new SnakeAndLadder();
         //set OptionalJump to true if the jump is optional
         //sal.OptionalJump = true;
         sal.AddJump(10,60);
         sal.AddJump(51,100);
         Console.WriteLine(sal.Solve());
         Console.ReadLine();
     }
    }
    }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Breadth First Search (BFS) Or Dynamic Programming solution will work in O(N) time using O(N) space.

Initialization: Keep an auxiliary array to keep the ladders and snakes. Suppose there's a ladder from xth to yth cell. So auxi[x] = y. If there's snake from cell x to y, `x>y` then keep `auxi[x]=-1`. If there's no ladder or snake from the current cell, keep auxi[x] = x;

A dynamic programming solution:

```
res[top]=0;
for(int i  = top-1; i>=0; i--) {

    res[i] = INF;
    for(int j=1; j<=6; j++){

        if(i-j<0)break;

        if(auxi[i+j]>-1)     // if i+jth cell is start of a snake, we'll always skip it
        res[i]=min( res[i] , res[auxi[i+j]]+1 );
    }

}
```

We'll always skip a cell where a snake starts because let's assume, on the x the cell a snake starts and it ends on the yth cell where, y

Comment: I think there must be something wrong with your code; it's accessing elements of `res` before they're initialized.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: Where? Please note that, I'm initializing `res[i] = INF;` before the inner loop.

Comment: Yes, but `auxi[i-j]` may be (and typically is) less than `i`. (I think that's probably a bug, and it should be `auxi[i+j]` since you're looping backwards from `top` to `0`, but even if you fix that, you'll still be referencing uninitialized elements whenever there's a snake.)

Comment: What is `res`, number of turns to reach the top from a certain position? And does your algorithm take into account that a solution potentially goes both up ladders and down snakes? Not sure if the `min()` takes that correctly into account, since you seem to look up board positions that might change value later ...

Comment: I did not study CS, but I do know what DP is. You get the downvotes because either your algo is very cryptic, or it is simply buggy. As both me and @IlmariKaronen noted, you are probably accessing uninitialized parts of `res` in case of a snake, you do not reply to that criticism in the comments. Your solution _might_ work if there are only ladders. But would it find a solution with a ladder from 1 to 80, another from 50 to 100 and a snake from 81 to 49? Probably not, when `i=80`, it does not yet know that 49 is 1 step away from the finish. Did you test your own code?

Answer (score 0):

Solution in C# in o(n).

Build an help matrix to go over each step and see what is the minimum way to get there and add one to it.

```
const int BoardSize = 100;
const int MaxStep = 6;
static void Main()
{

    // - means a ledder ending at the pos
    // + means a snake (taking you back n steps)
    int[] arr = new int[] {     
                            -1,     -1,     -1,     -1,     -1,     -1,     -1,     -1,     -1,     -1, 
                            -1,     -1,     -1,     -1,     -1,     -1,     -1,     -1,     -1,     -1,
                            -1,     -1,     -1,     -1,     -1,     -1,     -1,     -1,     -1,     -1, 
                            -1,     -1,     -1,     -1,     -1,     -1,     -1,     -1,     -1,     -1, 
                            -1,     -1,     -1,     -1,     -1,     -1,     -1,     -1,     -1,     -1, 
                            -1,     -1,     -1,     -1,      8,     -1,     -1,     -1,     -1,     -1, 
                            -1,     -1,     -1,     -1,     -1,     -1,     -1,     -1,     -1,     -1, 
                            -1,     -1,     -1,     -1,     -1,     -1,     -1,     -1,     -1,     -1, 
                            -1,     -1,     -1,     -1,     -1,     -1,     -1,     -1,     -1,     -1, 
                            -1,     -1,     -1,     -1,     -1,     -1,     -1,     -71,    -1,     -1      };

    Console.WriteLine("Steps needed: " + solve(arr));
}

public static int solve(int[] inArr)
{
    int[] arr = new int[BoardSize];

    arr[0] = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < BoardSize; ++i)
    {
        // steps here is the minimum of all the positions in all the previos 6 cells +1
        if (i < MaxStep)
            arr[i] = 1;
        else
        {
            int extraOption = int.MaxValue;
            if (inArr[i] < -1 || inArr[i] > 0)
                extraOption = arr[i + inArr[i]];
            else if (inArr[i] > 0)
                extraOption = arr[i + inArr[i]];
            arr[i] = min(arr[i - 1], arr[i - 2], arr[i - 3], arr[i - 4], arr[i - 5], arr[i - 6], extraOption) + 1;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < BoardSize; ++i)
    {
        Console.Write(arr[i] + "\t");
        if ((i + 1) % 10 == 0)
            Console.WriteLine("");
    }

    return arr[arr.Length-1];
}

public static int min(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e, int f, int g)
{
    int ab = Math.Min(a,b);
    int cd = Math.Min(c,d);
    int ef = Math.Min(e,f);
    return Math.Min(Math.Min(ab, cd), Math.Min(ef,g));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This program simulate actual scenario..kindly let me know if it meet the expectation or not..

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class SnakeLadder {

    private Map<Integer,Integer> snakeLadderMapping=new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();


    private int winPosition=100;
    private int currentPosition=1;

    public SnakeLadder(){
        snakeLadderMapping.put(9, 19);
        snakeLadderMapping.put(17, 5);
        snakeLadderMapping.put(12, 40);
        snakeLadderMapping.put(24, 60);
        snakeLadderMapping.put(68, 89);
        snakeLadderMapping.put(50, 12);
        snakeLadderMapping.put(84, 98);
        snakeLadderMapping.put(75, 24);
        snakeLadderMapping.put(72, 16);
    }

    public int startGame(){
        int count=0;
        while(currentPosition!=winPosition){
            count++;
            getNextPosition(rollDice());
        }
        System.out.println("Game Won!!!!!!");
        return count;
    }

    public int rollDice(){
        return 1+ (int)(Math.random()*5);
    }

    public void getNextPosition(int diceValue){
        int temp=currentPosition+diceValue;
        if(snakeLadderMapping.containsKey(temp)){
            currentPosition=snakeLadderMapping.get(temp);
        }else{
            if(temp<=winPosition){
                currentPosition=temp;
            }
        }
    }
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SnakeLadder l=new SnakeLadder();
        System.out.println("No of Steps to win:"+l.startGame());

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Consider each as a vertex in directed graph. 
   2.From cell 1 you can goto cells 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 so vertex 1 will have directed edge towards vertex 2, vertex 3….vertex 7. Similarly consider this for rest of the cells.
2. For snake- connect directed edge from head of snake vertex to tail of snake vertex.
3. For ladder- connect directed edge from bottom of ladder vertex to top of the ladder vertex.

   5. Now problem is reduced to Shorted path problem.So by Breadth-First Search (using queue) we can solve the problem.

See the complete code solution here - https://algorithms.tutorialhorizon.com/snake-and-ladder-problem/

Answer (score 0):

This Snake and Ladder game code build in **Python Programming Language**.

Simple code to win the snake and ladder game.

****************Code of SNAKE and LADDER GAME *************************

```
import random
import curses

s = curses.initscr()
curses.curs_set(0)
sh, sw = s.getmaxyx()
w = curses.newwin(sh, sw, 0, 0)
w.keypad(1)
w.timeout(100)

snk_x = sw/4
snk_y = sh/2
snake = [
    [snk_y, snk_x],
    [snk_y, snk_x-1],
    [snk_y, snk_x-2]
]

food = [sh/2, sw/2]
w.addch(food[0], food[1], curses.ACS_PI)

key = curses.KEY_RIGHT

while True:
    next_key = w.getch()
    key = key if next_key == -1 else next_key

    if snake[0][0] in [0, sh] or snake[0][1] in [0, sw] or snake[0] in snake[1:]:
        curses.endwin()
        quit()

    new_head = [snake[0][0], snake[0][1]]

    if key == curses.KEY_DOWN:
        new_head[0] += 1
    if key == curses.KEY_UP:
        new_head[0] -= 1
    if key == curses.KEY_LEFT:
        new_head[1] -= 1
    if key == curses.KEY_RIGHT:
        new_head[1] += 1

    snake.insert(0, new_head)

    if snake[0] == food:
        food = None
        while food is None:
            nf = [
                random.randint(1, sh-1),
                random.randint(1, sw-1)
            ]
            food =nf if nf not in snake else None
         w.addch(food[0], food[1], curses.ACS_PI)
    else:
        tail = snake.pop()
        w.addch(tail[0], tail[1], ' ')

     w.addch(snake[0][0], snake[0][1], curses.ACS_CKBOARD)
```